# ошибка expected primary expression

Tags: c++, ооп

Ошибка в коде в классе DRIVER внизу кода

```
class Date {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

    public:
        Date (int year, int month, int day) {
            this->year = year;
            this->month = month;
            this->day = day;
        }
};

class Bus {
    int seatsNumber;
    int petrolPer100km;

    public:
        Bus (int seatsNumber, int petrolPer100km) {
            this->seatsNumber = seatsNumber;
            this->petrolPer100km = petrolPer100km;
        }
};

class Person {

    string name;
    string surname;
    Date* birthday;

    public:
        Person ( string name, string surname, Date* birthday) {
            this->name = name;
            this->surname = surname;
            this->birthday = birthday;
        }
};

class Application {

    string finalPoint;
    int length; 

    public:
        Application (string finalPoint, int length) {
            this->finalPoint = finalPoint;
            this->length = length;
        }
};

class Driver : public Person {
    char category;
    float salary;
    string dateofadmission;

    public:
     Driver (string name, string surname, Date* birthday, char category, float salary, string dateofadmission) : Person ( Date* birthday, string name, string surname) // **ОШИБКА** [Error] expected primary-expression before 'name'
    { 
    }
};
```

Comment: `: Person ( Date* birthday` должно быть `: Person (birthday` потому что это инициализация объекта, а не объявление конструктора.

Comment: @VTT спасибо) сработало) не могу понять только почему без типа данных

Comment: тип данных у вас описан выше, среди параметров конструктора `Driver`